# Wildfly Deploy Maven - Remove Version

Tags: maven, deployment, wildfly, conflict

I want to deploy a war that I have created using maven to wildfly using the wildfly-maven-plugin.

---

The final name of the war is something like: **my-war-1.0.war**
The war also contains a **jboss-web.xml** specifying the **context root** (e.g. /my-war)

---

**Problem Description**

If I now deploy the war to wildfly I will get a **"my-war-1.0.war" deployment**.
If I later want to deploy a new version (e.g. the war is now named **my-war-1.1.war**) I get a conflict as the context root is already known but the deployment has a new name.

---

Is there a way using the wildfly-maven-plugin to deploy a "my-war.war" instead?

I need to keep the original final build name inside the maven build for versioning and deploying to our nexus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that I can use the parameters `<name/>` and `<runtimeName/>` inside the `<configuration/>` of the maven-wildfly-plugin.

That way I can specify what the deployment should be called on the server and each time just replace it. It is important to have the two parameters end in **".war"**, otherwise you will get a 404 error.

Using this method I can keep the original name of the final build result containing the version (my-app-1.0.war) and archive it inside our internal nexus repository.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is to use the `<finalName/>` element on the `<build/>` configuration.

```xml
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
</build>
```

You can use the maven war plugin to rename the final war. For Eg:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <warName>my-war</warName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This will always generate the war with the name my-war.war in your "target" directory.

Comment: The thing is that I do not want to change the name of the build result as mentioned in my question. I want it to contain the version information for archiving.

Comment: The name of the artifact will only change in the `target` directory. It would still get published as `my-war-1.0.war` in your local `.m2` repository.